# 433Mhz Receiver Low Range Only on Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, 433mhz

I have an Arduino mini pro with a 433mhz receiver attached. I connected this to my computer via a usb to serial cable. I've tried it on two laptops ans it works fine with it (>15 metres), but when connecting it to the Raspberry pi the range is REALLY bad (<1 metre).

I measured the voltage at the 433mhz receiver and it was slightly lower when it was connected to the raspberry pi. I tried to rule this add by adding a voltage booster circuit but it made it worst if anything.

laptop = 4.88v
raspberry pi = 4.3v
raspberry pi using booster circuit = 4.98v

I've not tried an external power supply yet.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about naming the parts and a circuit diagram with links to the receiver data sheet. It's too generic at the moment. BTW it's "MHz" not "Mhz" or "mhz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected up an external power supply to the receiver instead of using the power coming from the Raspberry Pi / Arduino. This made an amazing difference to the range.

For the receiver module I was working with 5.5V - 6V seemed to give the best range. Anything below 5V was pathetic.